# Spyder no compila códigos con inputs

Tags: python, spyder

El  spyder no compila códigos que contienen inputs, no se cómo solucionar este problema.

Acá los detalles que da el spyder al respecto:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\base_frontend_mixin.py", line 138, in _dispatch
> handler(msg)
>
> File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\debugging.py", line 278, in _handle_input_request
> return super(DebuggingWidget, self)._handle_input_request(msg)
>
> File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\frontend_widget.py", line 512, in _handle_input_request
> self._readline(msg['content']['prompt'], callback=callback, password=msg['content']['password'])
>
> File "C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\console_widget.py", line 2422, in _readline
> self._show_prompt(prompt, newline=False, separator=False)
> TypeError: _show_prompt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'separator'

Comment: Al parecer debe de haber un problema con el `keyword` `separator` que se usa en la función `_show_prompt()`, divagando por internet he encontrado que este problema se resuelve en la versión `5.3.0`, te adjunto [link de como solucionarlo](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17616#issuecomment-1088750490)

Comment: @adrigo ¡ponlo como respuesta! Y pon un resumen del contenido de ese enlace.

Comment: gracias, fue útil el enlace